# Add update date to topusers' page / No update to topusers' page

Tags: bug, feature-request, top-users

The footers of the topusers' pages read:

> Only non community-wiki questions and answers are included in these totals (updated daily)

But there has not been an update for a week or so.  If it is too costly to update the pages regularly, please just add the date of the last update to the footer.

Comment: I was just about to post the same thing. The figures are very stale now.

Comment: @DavidBacci [Just about to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423509/top-users-seems-to-be-stuck)?

Comment: Hi Robert - for some reason my question was annihilated yesterday so I deleted and decided to gather some evidence. I have screenshots from yesterday and today showing that the page is stale. Also when you click on the individual users, the number of questions doesn't match the number on the top users page. Even this question seems to be getting downvoted which I don't understand.

Comment: @DavidBacci Sounds like you should undelete your question and edit the evidence into it.

Comment: Thanks Robert. I'm not sure there is any point when the OP here is raising the same precise issue and it is trivial to recreate/verify. My screenshots are just two identical images taken over two different days so don't really add much to the discussion.

Comment: @DavidBacci: "for some reason my question was annihilated" - What do you mean  by "annihilated"? [Your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/423509/top-users-seems-to-be-stuck) has not closed and 0/-4 on meta could mean "slight disagreement": https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta. And if some of those downvotes mean a problems with the question post itself, then the comment  
from Samuel Liew defines what kind of problems they could be and how to solve them.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for your input. This is my first time on meta so I'm not familiar with protocol. As I see it, there is no point reopening my old question as this one here is asking the exact same thing. I don't want to derail OP's question with how my own was handled yesterday so will just watch the discussion here to see how things evolve. My only contribution is to say I can also observe what OP is seeing and it would be nice to get a fix deployed to update the page and/or a timestamp showing when figures were last updated.

Comment: @DavidBacci "[F]or some reason my question was annihilated yesterday..." the only "annihilation" of [your question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423509) was *your own edit* to it, which was tantamount to vandalism, replacing all of its content with "deleted deleted [etc.]". I agree that there is *now* no point in you undeleting your question, since this question has now been posted, and that would create pointless duplication. If you have evidence to share, then you can and should edit it into *this* question.